# How can I bring a string of array into file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Can you help me out to bring string of array which is in one text file say

```
Apple banana mango grapes
```

I should be get like each word in different line

```
Apple 
Banana 
Mango
Grape
```

and store in another text file using bash she'll

Comment: Please update the question with some sample code with what you've tried, and a clear explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -o`

```
grep -Eo '\w+' file
Apple
banana
mango
grapes
```

Answer (score 1):

use `tr`

```
echo "Apple banana mango grapes" | tr -s ' ' '\n'  > output
```

or sourced from file

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' <file > output
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure Bash:

```
set -o noglob
printf '%s\n' $(< file)
```

The `set -o noglob` is necessary to prevent pathname expansion (globbing) after `$(< file)` is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat stack.txt | tr ' ' '\n' >outfile.txt`

or just `cat stack.txt | tr ' ' '\n'`  for outputting on the terminal